# Using ArrayList of abstract class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, casting

I have an abstract class C0.
I have several other classes that inherit from C0. They override the abstract methods and have special methods of their own.

I want to create an ArrayList containing every one of those specialized classes.

Here is a chunk of code showing how I (want to) do it:

```
ArrayList<C0> A = new ArrayList<>();
A.add(new C1() );
A.add(new C2() );

A.get(x).method_of_C0(); // Works because my classes extend C0.
A.get(0).method_of_C1(); // Does not work
A.get(1).method_of_C2(); // Does not work
```

I would like to be able to call C1's and C2's own methods through this ArrayList. Would that be possible? I tried some tweaks by casting manually but I had no success.

Comment: => take a look at "polymorphism"

Comment: The hard way is to look, if there is the method through Reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to keep a separate ArrayList of C1 and C2 instances, or you have to cast them to their respective types to use the methods of the subtypes. Something like:

```
A.get(x).method_of_C0();
((C1)A.get(0)).method_of_C1();
((C2)A.get(1)).method_of_C2();
```

You might also use the **instanceof** keyword to check that an element is actually an instance of a particular subtype before you do the casting, otherwise you'll get a ClassCastException.

But note that this has a pretty bad code smell, so keeping track of each subtype as you need them is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not declaring an object type when instantiating a new Instance of the ArrayList.
Here is the easiest way to solve your problem:

```
ArrayList<C0> A = new ArrayList<C0>();
A.add( new C1() );
A.add( new C2() );
```

Now the following lines of code should work. As long as C1 and C2 are subclasses of C0.

```
A.get(0).method_C1();
A.get(1).method_C2();
```